# cannot figure out why this does not write into a new xml file anymore

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-serialization

recently i made some changes to the button "save" event and it just doenst write into the xml file or create a new one anymore. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong over here...My savepath string here looks ok to me though. Please help me figure out what is wrong with my code. Many thanks.

Here is my code:

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string savepath;
            SaveFileDialog DialogSave = new SaveFileDialog();
            // Default file extension
            DialogSave.DefaultExt = "txt";
            // Available file extensions
            DialogSave.Filter = "XML file (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            // Adds a extension if the user does not
            DialogSave.AddExtension = true;
            // Restores the selected directory, next time
            DialogSave.RestoreDirectory = true;
            // Dialog title
            DialogSave.Title = "Where do you want to save the file?";
            // Startup directory
            DialogSave.InitialDirectory = @"C:/";
            if (DialogSave.ShowDialog().Equals(true))
            {
                savepath = DialogSave.FileName;
                //DialogSave.Dispose();
                DialogSave = null;

                FormSaving formsaving = new FormSaving();
                formsaving.Builderemail = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
                formsaving.Manageremail = comboBox2.SelectedIndex;

                if (MajorversionresultLabel != null && MajorversionresultLabel.Content != null && MajorversionLabel.Content.ToString() != string.Empty)
                    formsaving.Majorversion = MajorversionresultLabel.Content.ToString();
                if (MinorversionresultLabel != null && MinorversionresultLabel.Content != null && MinorversionLabel.Content.ToString() != string.Empty)
                    formsaving.Minorversion = MinorversionresultLabel.Content.ToString();
                if (ProjectnumberresultLabel != null && ProjectnumberresultLabel.Content != null && ProjectnumberLabel.Content.ToString() != string.Empty)
                    formsaving.Projectnumber = ProjectnumberresultLabel.Content.ToString();
                if (BuildnumberresultLabel != null && BuildnumberresultLabel.Content != null && BuildnumberLabel.Content.ToString() != string.Empty)
                    formsaving.Buildnumber = BuildnumberresultLabel.Content.ToString();
                if (PreviousbuildversionresultLabel != null && PreviousbuildversionresultLabel.Content != null && PreviousbuildversionresultLabel.Content.ToString() != string.Empty)
                    formsaving.Previousbuildversion = PreviousbuildversionresultLabel.Content.ToString();

                formsaving.Startzbuildfrom = StartzbuildfromcomboBox.SelectedIndex;
                formsaving.Fullorsingle = FullorsinglecomboBox.SelectedIndex;
                formsaving.Builddrive = BuilddrivecomboBox.SelectedIndex;

                if (TruecmtipresultTextBlock != null && TruecmtipresultTextBlock.Text != null && TruecmtipresultTextBlock.Text != string.Empty)
                    formsaving.Truecmtip = TruecmtipresultTextBlock.Text;
                formsaving.Truecmcomments = TruecmcommentsresultTextBlock.Text;

                ...

                using (Stream savestream = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FormSaving));
                    serializer.Serialize(savestream, formsaving);
                }
            }
            DialogSave.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Why do you have `.Equals(true)` in there? Why not just `== true` or even just `if (DialogSave.ShowDialog())`

Comment: hi lasse, seems that when i do `== true` i have this error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult' and 'bool'

Answer (score 1):

Which SaveFileDialog class are you using ? The one from Microsoft.Win32 or the one from System.Windows.Forms ?

The first one returns bool?, so your code should be OK (except for setting DialogSave to null, then disposing it outside of the if block).

If you're using the second one, it returns a DialogResult enum, which can never equal 'true'.

Comment: Yeah, the `.Equals(true)` is a dead giveaway that there's something fishy with that code.

Comment: hi Timores its system.windows.forms

Comment: So this explains why it no longer saves. You should have a test like if (DialogSave.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

Answer (score 0):

I bet your original version of the code was using `SelectedItem` everywhere you're using `SelectedIndex`, unless you're really doing something horrible.

Also, good heavens, do you need to be using data binding.

Comment: i am using selected index so that i can get the index and reload the selection of the combo boxes.. any advice for this? i have more than 40 check boxes, 20 combo boxes and some textblocks and labels.. therefore i choose to use xml serialization

Comment: Well, the point is, you're saving an integer value in those variables.  Are you expecting the value of `formsaving.Builderemail` to be 3?

Comment: why not? i select the integer value of 3 when i load the xml file and it gives me the selected item from there.